# What's the difference between "mvn spring-boot:run" and "Add to Tomcat server" in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-boot

I downloaded a sample of Spring-boot CXF Web Services from [here](https://github.com/elans3/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-ws-cxf). I am able to run it sucessfully in Eclipse using:
*Right click on project> Run as>Maven build...>* and setting Goals: *spring-boot:run*

The server starts, everything is logged into the console.

Next I tried to deploy it on my Tomcat server in Eclipse (see [screenshot.png](https://github.com/elans3/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-ws-cxf)) but when the server is started the Spring is not started. No Spring info is logged into the console

According to the line from the log bellow it knows the Spring should start. So why it won't start properly?

```
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@4ed48c2]
```

the whole log:

```
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:spring-boot-sample-ws-cxf' did not find a matching property.
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Oct 7 2015 18:25:21 UTC
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.28.0
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\jre
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\cerny\JavaProjects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Tomcat 8.0
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\cerny\JavaProjects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 8.0
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\cerny\JavaProjects\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 8.0\endorsed
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_65/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\eclipse;;.
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1036 ms
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Led 07, 2016 3:39:18 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.28
Led 07, 2016 3:39:25 ODP. org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Led 07, 2016 3:39:25 ODP. org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration@4ed48c2]
Led 07, 2016 3:39:25 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Led 07, 2016 3:39:25 ODP. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Led 07, 2016 3:39:25 ODP. org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 7300 ms
```

Comment: The Spring boot has an embedded server. As I remember it is Jetty. No need to separate server to run spring boot application. Anyway you can use the tomcat also as an embedded server.

Comment: What's your question, then: *"what's the difference"* or *"why it won't start?"*

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why it won't start. Now it is working for me. For running on eclipse tomcat you need to add `extends SpringBootServletInitializer` to the project's main class App.java

So the result will look like

```
package com.foo.bar;

import some.imported.package
import another.imported.package

@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

jar which is generated out of spring boot project will have tomcat server in it. You can just start the server using following command

```
java -jar XXX.jar
```